# How to run a JMeter JMX file in Java code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to run a JMeter MS SQL database test plan from Java code through my Spring Boot app but it's showing the following errors:

[image: screenshot of error message]
[image: screenshot of error message]

I have loaded the plugin manager in JMeter and put that in jmeter/lib/ext folder and installed all required plugins.

Java code to run JMeter test case:

```java
package com.example.demofin;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demofin.config.Properties;

@Component
public class Demofin implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;

    private Summariser result;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        for(String i : args)
            System.out.println(i);
          // String j = properties.getPropertyByKey("JMETER_HOME");
           String j="D:\\apache-jmeter-4.0";
//         System.out.println(j);
           //System.out.println("Jmeter home path: " + properties.getPropertyByKey("JMETER_HOME"));

               StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();       
//           // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.        
             JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(j);
             JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(j+"/bin/jmeter.properties");
//          
//           // you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level  
             JMeterUtils.initLogging();  
             JMeterUtils.initLocale();  

             // Initialize JMeter SaveService  
             SaveService.loadProperties();  

             // Load existing .jmx Test Plan  
             HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("D:\\apache-jmeter-4.0\\" + "bin\\JDBC Connection Configuration.jmx"));  

             Summariser summer = null;  
             String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");  

             if (summariserName.length() > 0) {  
               summer = new Summariser(summariserName);  
             }  

         ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);  
         testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);  
             // Run JMeter Test  
             jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);  
         jmeter.run();  
         result = summer;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you would like to execute your tests you could also look into jmeter-maven.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we compile java code to `jar` and push it to `jmeter/lib/ext` and use it in Jmeter.

If you attempt to using Jmeter in java, I suggest downloading source code of JMeter and merge to your project.

Comment: but its not the case with other test plans,its only mssql test plan that is raising such issues,all other test plans are runnning  perfectly by the provided java code.Also the same test plan is working fine if i run that by jmeter GUI.its just the code which is raising issues for mssql test plan